# Working for a company based in US remotely from India

Tags: visa, legal

I have a job offer from a company based in the US and they want me to start working full-time while they do my H1B visa transfer from one of my previous employers to this one. I currently work in India.

It is a contract position for now.

I would like to ask you how will this work legally. Would it be a `1099` contract or something else because I wont be physically present in the US?

Answer (score 2):

1099 is the form used to report payments to contractors where the payer and the payee are US entities for tax purposes.

If you're a US tax resident - you'll receive this form. If you're not - you probably won't.

That's just a form.

Comment: US tax resident? Didnt get that. I am a citizen of India.

Comment: @RahulDesai I'm not sure I understand your confusion. The fact that you're an Indian citizen has nothing to do with your tax residency. Being on H1b status you're likely to have been a US tax resident, and depending when you left the US - you may still be.

Comment: Earlier when I was working in the US, I was not on H1B, I used the CPT work permit provided by my school. Also, I have paid all taxes till date in US and India. So, I have never worked on H1B till date. I am trying to avoid 1099 to save on taxes. Having given this information, will I still get 1099?

Comment: @RahulDesai as I said - 1099 is just a piece of paper. What exactly are you trying to avoid?

Comment: I am trying to avoid the US taxes. EDIT: and also Indian taxes.

Comment: @RahulDesai you'll have to pay taxes in India, that's for sure. As  to the US - it depends on your tax status in the US, which we don't know.

Comment: My tax status is that I have paid all taxes so far, if that is what you mean?

Comment: No, I mean your tax residency status.